# Cannot get a valid response from Docker Registry remote API

Tags: node.js, api, docker, docker-registry

I'm using Nodejs & [request](https://github.com/request/request) to form my API calls, I can make API calls directly to a UnixSocket with it however it fails every attempt when requesting from the Docker registry container I have running, so I believe it's the fault of my registry configuration.

I've set it up out of the box [just like the doc](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/) steps below.

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry registry:2
docker pull alpine
docker tag alpine localhost:5000/alpine
docker push localhost:5000/alpine
```

The code I'm using to request is below, it receives a `404 not found`.

```
  const request = require('request')
  request({
    method: 'GET',
    uri: 'http://localhost:5000/images/json', // status 404
    // uri: 'http://unix:/var/run/docker.sock:/images/json', // this works 
    headers: { host : 'localhost' }
  }, (e, res, body) => {
    if(e) return console.error(e)
    console.log(res.statusCode == 200 ? JSON.parse(body) : res.statusCode)
  })
```

To be clear, this code is just to demonstrate that I'm making a GET request that should be well-formed.

What has to be done to allow a running registry container respond to the remote API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker Registry doesn't have the `/images/json` API, and the Docker Registry's API does not compatible with docker engine API.

To get the image list of Docker Registry, please try `GET /v2/_catalog`. Full document can be found [here](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/#/listing-repositories).

Comment: Wow. I can't believe I completely missed that fact. Thanks for the quick reply and the doc reference!